# Pubnub perform sync request

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, pubnub

I have this asynchronous request:

```
Pubnub pn = new Pubnub(publishKey, subscribeKey, secretKey, cipherKey, enableSSL);

pn.HereNow("testchannel", res => //doesn't return a Task
{ //response
}, err =>
{ //error response
});
```

The problem is that I don't know how to run it synchronously. Please help.

Comment: What's Pubnub? Is that yours.

Comment: Nope http://pubnub.com

Comment: synchronously or asynchronously?

Comment: @i3arnon I'd like to perform this request synchronously. So I need to wait for a callback somehow.

Comment: Please shoot us an email at support@pubnub.com and we'd be happy to assist you.

Comment: @AndreiM did you contact pubnub via email for this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with pubnub, but what you're trying to achieve should be as simple as this:

```
Pubnub pn = new Pubnub(publishKey, subscribeKey, secretKey, cipherKey, enableSSL);

var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<PubnubResult>();

pn.HereNow("testchannel", res => //doesn't return a Task
{ //response
    tcs.SetResult(res);
}, err =>
{ //error response
    tcs.SetException(err);
});

// blocking wait here for the result or an error
var res = tcs.Task.Result; 
// or: var res = tcs.Task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Note that doing asynchronous stuff synchronously is not recommend. You should look at using `async/await`, in which case you'd do:

```
var result = await tcs.Task;
```

Comment: Awesome. Works perfectly for me.

Comment: Good solution, thanks. Last line should be var res = tcs.Task.Result

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue using the @Noseratio ideia with a simple enhancement.

```
private Task<string> GetOnlineUsersAsync()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

    _pubnub.HereNow<string>(MainChannel,
        res => tcs.SetResult(res),
        err => tcs.SetException(new Exception(err.Message)));

    return  tcs.Task; 
}

// using
var users = await GetOnlineUsersAsync();
```